# CSS / Font - Mixed content issue

Tags: html, css, webpack

I'm getting a "mixed content" error on my website due to one font being loaded over HTTP.

My font is included in a css file like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontXYZ';
  src: url('../font/fontXYZ.eot');
  src: url('../font/fontXYZ.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../font/fontXYZ.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../font/fontXYZ.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../font/fontXYZ.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../font/fontXYZ.svg#fontXYZ') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

With webpack I bundle this css with other various css in one file.

On my website the css looks like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontXYZ';
  src: url(fontXYZ.eot);
  src: url(fontXYZ.eot#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
       url(fontXYZ.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(fontXYZ.woff) format('woff'),
       url(fontXYZ.ttf) format('truetype'),
       url(fontXYZ.svg#fontXYZ) format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

All solutions that I found suggest that I change the URL to HTTPS or that I use '//' but I don't see how I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

include font like this...

```
@font-face {src: url(font/Roboto-Bold.ttf);font-family: RobotoBold;}
```

font/Roboto-Bold.ttf - font file inside fonts folder(path of the file)
use font family like below..

```
.banner_header{font-family: RobotoBold;}
```

Comment: I don't want to be rude but this doesn't seem to address my problem at all.